# Is it possible to be using a library in a method but not outside the method?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
private void MethodName()
{
    Using System.OI;
}
```

I only need this library in this one method. Is there any way I can do this?

The reason I don't have it up top is the it creates ambiguous references.

Comment: You don't have to use `using`. You can just fully qualify the symbols from that namespace:  `System.OI.Foo = new System.OI.Foo();`

Comment: what is your motivation to be able to do this?  for example, are you trying to control memory consumption?  (if yes, you might be able to dynamically load and unload the library .dll) ... if you explain your purpose, you might get the answer that you require.  Note that every solution has pros and cons, for example, if you load/unload a library multiple times, you may get an unwanted and intolerable performance hit.

Comment: @gerryLowry It has nothing to do with whether or not a class library is in memory.  It's purely a matter of ambiguous type references.  For example, if he has a separate library with it's own `File` type (a situation I've run into myself) then it can cause problems without having some means of disambiguating the type.

Comment: @Servy oops, blindness on my part; i missed Augs last sentence about ambiguous references.  FWIW, John Saunders comment above and your FQN answer below should suffice for Augs case.  Augs, showing your peers the actual offending line of code is often useful.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need at all to use a `using` statement when using a given type.  You can simply use the fully qualified name when you want to use the type:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines("temp.txt");
```

The `using` statement is merely syntactic sugar to avoid needing to do this for every single use of a type.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**partial classes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx). Create *two* source files for the same class, one that imports System.IO (and contains your special method) and one that doesn't (and contains all the remaining methods).

```
using System.IO;

public partial class MyClass
{
    private void MethodName()
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Very clever as long as partial classes are allowed!

Comment: This is way more work than is necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: @Servy, That depends on how many times he needs the namespace. If its a lot (but he still needs to avoid the `using` directive) this would be much cleaner.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET In most cases a type/namespace alias would still be better than this.  Pushing the code to another file like this is a pretty significant deterrent on readability.  Also keep in mind that VS can prepend the fully qualified name on your behalf, so between that and effective use of type inference, you can really cut down on the actual amount of work it puts on you.

Answer (score 0):

This line from MSDN makes me suspect not:

> The scope of a using directive is limited to the file in which it appears.

Note that it doesn't say scope. However, you can always reference an object without a `using` directive:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter myWriter;
}
```

The partial class idea is another clever way around the problem. Here's the documentation I reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

While most answers here about avoiding `using` statement and full qualified type name, I want to comment on this one:

> > I only need this library in this one method. Is there any way I can do this?

In .Net, adding `using` or adding reference to a library doesn't mean that this library will be loaded at all. Library is being loaded to application domain in runtime only then it is really used.

So adding using to a file don't hurt anyone; executing particular method will load necessary libraries if required.

Once library is loaded in application domain - it will never be unloaded.

So most probably - you won't need what you are asking for, just use using on file level or namespace aliases in case of names conflicts.